# Add prefix in every line of multiple txt files

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have 40,000 different notepad files in a folder and I want to add a prefix in every line of notepad and do same for 40,000 files how?

I cannot do huge big task to open each file and adding a prefix (will takes months).
I want to know how to add a prefix in notepad++, but I have 40,000 files to do. Any tricks or software, so how I can do it all at once?

Comment: what kind of prefix? how is your programming skills? it is fairly easy using a programming language to do this, but i dont know how long it would take for 40k files with a large number of lines. you can check online for techniques/tutorials on how to read/write data files on any language you choose

Comment: i want to add a word before every line in notepad,..& same for 40000 notpad files..

Comment: ok, is it a common word for each file or line? or just some "random" word. how about your programming skills?

Comment: it is a common word,..and i don't have any skills in programing..

Comment: no programming skill, that is a stopper for me. I dont know any software that would do that for you. I am sure that there must be a way to do it under a linux distro, but dont know for sure.

Comment: ok..if you get just post here Dear..thanks

Comment: I HAVE GOT A  ANSWER ,I CAN USE AUTOMATIC CLICKER WITH SUPPORTS KEYS TOO. JUST RUNNING..happy

Comment: use notepad++ replace in files feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that easily with Notepad++.

Go to the Find dialogue and there to the Find in Files tab

[image]

- Find what: `^` is a regular expression for the start of the row
- Replace with your prefix
- Filters: You can use a file filter, e.g. *.txt would only work on txt files
- Directory: The directory you want to search-replace in
- Search Mode: Regular Expression, to make the `^` work.

Please test it first on a subset of your 40000 files and make a backup before you run your replacement.

Comment: Perfect Solution ,I Getting Good Results ,From Where Do you Learn this Lethal~Stuff 's ...?// {Solution Working GREAT}